# how does oracle makes 1 million insertion in 1 second

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, postgresql

Few years ago, I found oracle can achieve 1 million insertion in 1 second, first let me explain this, I remember in SQL/PLUS interactive command line

```
set timing on
create table tbl as 
select ROWNUM c1, 
       dbms_random.string('x', 6) c2, 
       sysdate + ROWNUM / 24 / 3600 c3 
  from dual 
connect by level < 1000000
```

above code will create one table with 1 million records, and SQL/PLUS will give you the elapsed time.
That was on Windows XP(SP3) PC machine, vendor is Lenovo Think Centre, forgot the model, hardware performance was not bad.

But I tested MySQL PostgreSQL even sqlite, because I could not find one statement to generate millions result for them, then I made one loop, something like

```
declare i int default 0;
start transaction;
when i < 1000000
do
    insert into tbl values(i, rand(), now() + interval 1 second);
    set i = i + 1;
end when;
commit;
```

not exactly, something like that, but it takes several seconds to finish that, only makes 200~300K per second, basically the same hardware, but on Linux

I was wondering what mechanism oracle have, I'm sure the whole point is the IO with the disk, I know oracle has one Segment for this table(since there is not index), inside that has many extends, and then blocks, I think it allocates more than needs to reduce allocate frequency, bulk flush, better internal structure, but I'm not sure, I don't think only such way can makes such huge improvement, besides I think other rdbms also has such way, but why...

Comment: Maybe you mean: `(sysdate() + 1) / 24 / 3600 c3` ??

Comment: Sorry, I mean sysdate() + rownum / 24 / 3600

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing apples to oranges. In Oracle you are doing a create table based on a select which is a bulk insert. The second code example is doing 1 million single inserts which are always ***way*** slower than a bulk insert.

You also tagged this with Postgres, so please try the following there:

```
create table tbl as 
select i as c1, 
       random() as c2, 
       clock_timestamp() + interval '1' second as c3 
  from generate_series(1,1000000) i
;
```

Comment: I am not able to test 1 million loop insertion into oracle right now, but Clodoaldo verified postgresql can also makes 1 million in 1 second, bulk way, then at least Oracle has no exclusive magic. Going to accept this information

Answer (score 4):

In my desktop Oracle takes 31 seconds and Postgresql 1 second

Oracle:

```
set timing on
create table tbl as 
select ROWNUM as c1, 
       dbms_random.string('x', 6) as c2, 
       sysdate + ROWNUM / 24 / 3600 as c3
from dual 
connect by level < 1000000;
orcl >   2    3    4    5    6  
Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:31.33
```

Postgresql (using [**_a_horse_with_no_name**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24549226/131874) code):

```
create table tbl as 
select i as c1, 
    random() as c2, 
    clock_timestamp() + interval '1' second as c3 
from generate_series(1,1000000) i
;
SELECT 1000000
Time: 1168.918 ms
```

But I do not consider the above numbers meaningful because performance comparisons involve lots of factors which are very difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Now, becoming more interesting, I am not able to explain, but it makes no sense

Comment: The `from dual connect by level` trick is useful for creating fake rows but has never performed very well.  Creating a hierarchical result set is a lot of work and uses a lot of memory.  On many systems even 1 million rows will throw the error `ORA-30009: Not enough memory for CONNECT BY operation`.